# How to retrieve Inference image location for my Sagemaker pytorch custom model for Model registry

Tags: amazon-web-services, version-control, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I'm new to AWS Sagemaker. I have deployed my custom PyTorchModel using Sagemaker Studio following [this tutorial from AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/hosting-yolov8-pytorch-model-on-amazon-sagemaker-endpoints/). Now, I'm trying to do model versioning through model registry following [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-registry-version.html#model-registry-studio). I need to know my Inference image location for Inference container specification. However, I couldn't find any relevant document to retrieve this. The only thing I could understand so far is that AWS is handling all the containers where my model and inference code reside.